# Как найти набор записей, по колонке и по соответствию номера строки в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Имеется такая схема базы данных. (дамп [тут](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/TSD1/MAnxg6aoe))
[image: схема бд].

- Колонки.
- Наборы.
- Номера колонок.
- Наборы - колоноки

Пример заполнения таблицы наборы - колонки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется массив очередности колонок, по которому нужно найти набор из таблицы.

Пример.

```
[
    'column_1' => '1'
    'column_2' => '2'
    'column_3' => '3'
    'column_4' => '5'
    'column_5' => '4'
]
```

Нужно найти значение `bundle_id` (1 на скрине)  по значениям колонки `column_id` (2 на скрине).

Но к сожалению, совершенно не представляю как это сделать запросом в MySQL.
Если конечно такое вообще возможно...

P.S. Есть конечно мысль добавить поле скажем `sequence` в таблицу `bundle`, сделать по ней ключь строковой, и писать туда ключь последовательности, например так `1::1-2::2-3:3-4::5-5::4`, и потом по этому полю тупо искать.

Бадет даже частичный поиск по вхождению через LIKE работать.

Comment: Нужно найти ``bundle_id`` по вашему массиву, в данном случае column_1, column_2, column_3... и тд?

Comment: ``SELECT * FROM `column_bundle` WHERE `bundle_id` IN '(' . implode(',', $ВАШ_МАССИв) .')'``

Comment: @YaMus причем тут IN когда в таблице имеется все возможные варианты перестановок полей, ну выдаст он мне из 120 наборов абсолютно все 120 ибо все 120 наборов содержат эти самые IN 1,2,3,4,5. То есть они все обязательно содержат эти колонки только у них последовательнось разная, и надо найти точное совпадение именно последовательности, а то что они есть во всех конфигурациях мы и так знаем....

Comment: Все 600 записей, из 120 наборов https://c2n.me/4gJjzBy

Comment: Не причем, это был вопрос.

Comment: Обьясните нормально что вы хотите?

Comment: @YaMus я уже все пояснил, насколько смог, теперь ваша очередь задать вопрос что вам не понятно